# How to implement the graph adjacency array model?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

The paper ["Quantum query complexity of some graph problems"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401091) by Durr et al. introduces the **adjacency array model** as a way of storing a graph on a quantum computer. For a vertex $v_i$ of degree $d_i$, the adjacency array is a function $f_i:[d_i]\to [n]$ such that $f_i(j)$ is the $j^{\text{th}}$ neighbor of $v_i$.

In the last paragraph of page 2, the authors say that the time complexity of implementing the adjacency array is logarithmic; however, I have so far been unsuccessful in finding a quantum algorithm implementing this in logarithmic time.

What is a quantum algorithm for implementing an adjacency list in logarithmic time?